# add content to div according to input value

Tags: javascript, html, input

I know this is a really simple question, but how do I add content to a div when the user types into a input field and hits enter?

I have tried:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        function bleh() {
            var from = document.getElementById('setter').value;
            x = document.getElementById("mything");
            x.innerHTML = from;
        }
    }
})
```

my HTML is:

```
    <input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" id="setter" 

   onkeydown="writeit(this, event);moveIt(this.value.length, event)"  

    onkeyup="writeit(this, event)" onkeypress="writeit(this, event);"></input>
```

if you want to see it in action, go to thomaswd.com/cmd. start typing and hit enter.

again, this sounds like a really simple question, but I cant get it working. Thanks!!!

Comment: where's your writeit function ? Also beware, you seem to have a global variable `x`

Comment: its on another javascript file, but its unrelated to this

Comment: Are your div or input elements in a content page ?

Comment: function writeit(from, e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var w = $("writer");
    var tw = from.value;
    w.innerHTML = nl2br(tw);
   }

Comment: my div is on the main index.php page

Comment: what is the error u are getting

Comment: no error, but no results either

Comment: where yo u have mything div.can u show it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were really close:

```
document.getElementById("setter").addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
    var from = this.value;
    x = document.getElementById("mything");
    x.innerHTML = from;
    }
})
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9bbR2/

Although I would recommend using jQuery, it's much simpler.

```
$(function() {
  $("#setter").keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        $("#mything").text($(this).val());
    }
  });
});
```